# How do I connect a chandelier to this ceiling wiring?

Tags: wiring, ceiling, connectors

I just moved in to a 16 year old house and replacing a ceiling fan with chandelier. Chandelier has conventional white, black and ground. The fan was connected to red and ground only, which I guess was incorrect. How do I connect the new chandelier. Picture of the outlet attached.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to test to verify, but it looks like the black is a constant hot  with the red being the switch leg.

So to connect a chandelier you'd use the red (hot), white (neutral) and ground.

Comment: Yes, that's what i did. Tested, and black was constant hot and red was the switch. You got it spot on. Thanks.